# What is a good thermodynamics book with problems and solutions?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, education

I’m looking for a good book on thermodynamics with problems and solutions at an undergraduate level. Please let me know if you know any.

Comment: I really like Findamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.

Comment: Thermal physics by Blundell & Blundell (emphasis on statistical physics, not an engineering book).